# Last 5 orders per user from orders table using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to pull last 5 orders per user from my orders table using mysql but some how could not do it.

Orders are arranged by date.

I need to pull last 5 orders per user using mysql

Table structure:

Order, BuyerId, Date

Orders are stored like this:

```
1,1,2013-07-01
2,1,2013-07-02
3,2,2013-07-03
4,2,2013-07-04
5,3,2013-07-06
6,2,2013-07-07
7,2,2013-07-08
8,1,2013-07-09

etc
```

OrderId is primary index,unique

Please help me out, i have tried hours for this but some how could not do it.

Comment: you need 2 things order by and LIMIT

Comment: @Dagon - Also needs grouping.

Comment: This is a very basic question that a simple google search would return

Comment: you should better read [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Comment: If it's just about a query, you can leave PHP out of the question.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you -- you need to establish a row number per group:

```
select *
from (
  select BuyerId, Date, 
    @rn:=if(@prevBuyerId=BuyerId,@rn+1,1) rn, 
    @prevBuyerId:=BuyerId
  from orders 
    join (select @rn:=0, @prevBuyerId:=0 ) t
  order by BuyerId, Date desc
  ) t
where rn <= 5
```

Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bba76/5

*On a side note, I'm surprised about the comments using limit and group by...*

Comment: My table has over 290,000 entries, i think output of query will be slow

Comment: @DavidSmith -- honestly that isn't many records for most modern RDBMS.  Using MySQL, user-defined variables are the only option I know of for a single query.  Give it a try and let us know if it isn't working well.  Cheers!

Comment: This is a neat solution; I tried it on a large data set I had to hand and it works well and quickly. Only a minor change is required to order by buyer ID and order ID rather than buyer ID and date, which could give incorrect results (though less likely if date included time).

Comment: It worked but not the complete query select * from ( ) t
where rn <= 5 is not working numbering part is working

Comment: Why were you surprised that people were suggesting `limit` and `group by`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also pull the last five orders within a single row by doing:

```
select buyerid, substring_index(group_concat(order order by date desc), ',', 5) as orders5
from orders o
group by buyerid;
```

This returns them in a comma-delimited list.  If you wanted to actually get the orders, you could then join back to them:

```
select o.*
from orders o join
     (select buyerid, substring_index(group_concat(order order by date desc), ',', 5) as orders5
      from orders o
      group by buyerid
     ) b
     on o.buyerid = b.buyerid and
        find_in_set(o.orderid, b.orders5) > 0;
```

However, I would expect the version with the variables to perform better.